# Pig Latin Application in rust

Tags: rust

Just finished an exercise in the Rust online book and I wanted to know if there is anything worth talking about in the code I wrote... if there's any mistake or optimization possible.

**Convert strings to pig latin**

- The first consonant of each word is moved to the end of the word and
  “ay” is added, so “first” becomes “irst-fay”.
- Words that start with
  a vowel have “hay” added to the end instead (“apple” becomes
  “apple-hay”).
- Keep in mind the details about UTF-8 encoding!

```
use std::io;
fn main() {
    let mut user_input = String::new();
    io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut user_input)
        .expect("Failed to read line.");
    for word in user_input.split_whitespace() {
        match word.chars().nth(0).unwrap() {
            'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' | 'y' => print!("{} ", format!("{}-hay", word.trim())),
            _ => print!("{} ", format!("{}{}-ay", &word[word.chars().next().unwrap().len_utf8()..].trim(), word.chars().nth(0).unwrap())),
        };
    }
    println!();
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Code Review! Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Some small remarks:

- according to the documentation, you want to output `irst-fay` on `first`, but your code will output `irstf-ay` instead
- your code will only work on lower case words, but not on "Apple"
- instead of `print!("{} ", format!(...))` use `print!(...)`
- instead of `nth(0)` use `next()`
- I recommend you to format your code with `rustfmt`
- instead of `&word[word.chars().next().unwrap().len_utf8()..]` you can use `c.len_utf8()` if you name your match instead of using `_`, e.g.

  ```
  match word.chars().nth(0).unwrap() {
       'a' | 'e' | 'i' | 'o' | 'u' | 'y' => print!("{}-hay ", word.trim())),
        c => print!("{}-{}ay ", &word[c.len_utf8()..].trim(), c),
  };
  ```
- if you know that your index will end up at a proper UTF8 boundary you can use `&word[1..]` and `&word[..1]` instead of your indexing, but your variant is a lot safer. **Well done here**, as invalid string slicing is a common error in first Rust experiences :)

Comment: Thank you very much ! I've updated the code on my machine and passed it trough rustfmt once again and also fixed it so it supports uppercase and lowercase :D

Comment: @h4k that sounds great!. As a further exercise, write `fn piglatin(input : &str) -> String` (or a similar function) and additional tests as in [Chapter 11](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch11-01-writing-tests.html). Don't worry about jumping over chapter 9 and 10, both aren't necessary to write simple tests :). The `first` and `Apple` test cases should both be covered, as well as an empty string.